# Stop Child Data object automatically altering the parent data object

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, interface, data-objects

I'm working on a winform application, that has been setup with a main form and child forms within a **plugin** of the **parent** form.

I have a data object stored on the main form and I use an interface to Get the dataobject content to set the local private data object within the child form.

This local private data object then get amended, with data\actions of the plugin.
When I move off, I notice the main data object within the **Parent** form already contains the changes, so I do not need to set the Parent with the child amendments.

This can be useful, but I have a scenario where I do not want to keep the child changes.
How can I make sure the parent does not inherit the child change automatically?

Any help would be greatful

Comment: This is the nature of a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). If you are looking for a way to cancel changes, you should not pass the object or if you passed, provide a mechanism to keep original values to be able to cancel changes. The solution depends on the exact requirement, but as an option you can pass a `Clone` of your object to the child form. Then you can decide to apply changes of clone on original object or cancel changes.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone down the clone route and it does what is needed.  Again thanks @RezaAghaei